# Why data.frame column is not changing in R

Tags: r

I have following data frame:

```
ddf
  vnum1     vnum2
1     1 0.6380312
2     1 0.1737218
3     1 0.3528707
4     1 0.8670922
5     1 0.6498109
> 
> 
> str(ddf)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ vnum1: num  1 1 1 1 1
 $ vnum2: num  0.638 0.174 0.353 0.867 0.65
>
```

I want to change all values of vnum1 from 1 to 4.

Why following do not work:

```
> rbind(ddf, ddf[,1]=4)
Error: unexpected '=' in "rbind(ddf, ddf[,1]="
```

Following adds only one number and that too to both columns. It is obviously not working correctly.

```
> rbind(ddf, (ddf[,1]=4))
  vnum1     vnum2
1     1 0.6380312
2     1 0.1737218
3     1 0.3528707
4     1 0.8670922
5     1 0.6498109
6     4 4.0000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here.

1. The code doesn't work because `=` as you're using it in the argument list of a function is incorrect. In `rbind`, `=` is used to assign names to the arguments.

   To see this, try `rbind(ddf, ddf[,1] <- 4)` versus `rbind(ddf, ddf[,1]=4)`

   Also try `rbind(ddf, X = 3)` and look at the row names.
2. `rbind` is a **row bind** function.  So when you call `rbind(ddf, ddf[,1]=4)` you are trying to add a new row filled with 4's to the bottom of `ddf`.

---

That said, to replace all the values in the first column with 4, you can just use `ddf[,1]=4`, like you have in your `rbind` call, or you can also do

```
ddf$vnum1 <- 4L
```

Comment: Yes it works, but that means both changing numbers and rbind cannot be in the same statement.

Comment: Why are you asking about `rbind`?  I've explained `rbind`, and your question only asks how to change the values in the first column to 4?